# React-Redux : Child component not re-rendering on parent state change when using connect() in child

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am new to Reactjs and have been trying to create a real world website using React-Redux.

Here in my WebApp, when there is a state change in **Home** (Parent Component) ,       child component **HomePage** does not re-render. I will explain in detail below,

This is my Parent Component,

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import NavBar from './../components/NavBar';
import HomePage from './../components/Home/HomePage';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {loadCity} from './../actions/MainPage';
import Footer from './../components/Footer';
import {instanceOf} from 'prop-types';
import {withCookies, Cookies} from 'react-cookie';

class Home extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.rerender = this
            .rerender
            .bind(this);

        this.state = {
            renderFlag: false
        }
    }

    static propTypes = {
        cookies: instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this
            .props
            .loadCity();

    }

    rerender() {
        this.setState({
            renderFlag: !this.state.renderFlag
        })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <NavBar placelist={this.props.result} rerenderfun={() => this.rerender()}/>
                <HomePage/>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {result: state.cityReducer}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        loadCity: () => {
            dispatch(loadCity());
        }
    };
};

export default withCookies(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home));
```

Here in my **NavBar** component I have to select city. When I click on city a state change occurs in **HOME** (Parent Component) which causes child components to re-render. But all the child components **except HomePage** re-render.

But if I remove **connect()** from **HomePage**, then this page gets re-rendered.

Here is my code for HomePage,

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SearchSection from './SearchSection';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {loadInfoData} from './../../actions/MainPage';
import {instanceOf} from 'prop-types';
import {withCookies, Cookies} from 'react-cookie';
import InfoSection from './../../container/Home/InfoSection ';

class HomePage extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        cookies: instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        const {cookies} = this.props;
        this.setState({
            city: cookies.get('place')
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this
            .props
            .loadInfoData(this.state.city);
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log('Component WILL UPDATE!');
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div><SearchSection/>  <InfoSection result={this.props.result}/> 

            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {data: state.cityReducer}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        loadInfoData: (selectedCity) => {
            dispatch(loadInfoData(selectedCity));
        }
    };
};

export default withCookies(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePage));
```

Please help me find the issue and resolve it. I want **HomePage** to get re-rendered on **Home** state change.

**UPDATE**

Reducer

```
let defaultState = {
    result: "",
    info: "",
    recentlyadded: ""
}

const cityReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    if (action.type === "GET_CITY") {
        return {
            ...state,
            result: action.result
        }
    } else if (action.type === "GET_INFO_DATA") {
        return {
            ...state,
            info: action.result
        }
    } else if (action.type === "GET_MAIN_RECENTLY_ADDED") {
        return {
            ...state,
            recentlyadded: action.result
        }
    } else {
        return {
            ...state
        }
    }
}

export default cityReducer;
```

Action

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function loadCity() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios
            .get("**RESTAPILINK**")
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch(getPlace(response.data.result));
            })
    }
}

export function getPlace(result) {
    return {type: "GET_CITY", result}
}

export function loadInfoData(selectedCity) {
    var url = "**RESTAPILINK**" + selectedCity;
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios
            .get(url)
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch(getInfoData(response.data));
            })
    }
}

export function getInfoData(result) {
    return {type: "GET_INFO_DATA", result}
}

export function loadRecentlyAdded(selectedCity) {
    var url = "**RESTAPILINK**" + selectedCity;
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios
            .get(url)
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch(getRecentlyAdded(response.data));
            })
    }
}

export function getRecentlyAdded(result) {
    return {type: "GET_MAIN_RECENTLY_ADDED", result}
}
```

My NavBar component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Collapse,
    Navbar,
    NavbarToggler,
    NavbarBrand,
    Nav,
    NavItem
} from 'reactstrap';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import cityicon from '../assets/images/city/Bangalore.png';
import {instanceOf} from 'prop-types';
import {withCookies, Cookies} from 'react-cookie';

class NavBar extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggle = this
            .toggle
            .bind(this);

        this.toggleHidden = this
            .toggleHidden
            .bind(this);

        this.closeOverlay = this
            .closeOverlay
            .bind(this);

        this.escFunction = this
            .escFunction
            .bind(this);

        this.handleClick = this
            .handleClick
            .bind(this);

        this.state = {
            isOpen: false,
            isHidden: true,
            isLocation: false,
            city: "Select your city",
            classname: "city-section"
        };
    }

    static propTypes = {
        cookies: instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired
    };

    componentWillMount() {

        const {cookies} = this.props;
        let newstate = (cookies.get('place') != null)
            ? true
            : false;
        if (newstate) {
            this.setState({
                city: cookies.get('place')
            });
        }
        this.setState({isLocation: newstate, isHidden: newstate});

    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
        });
    }

    toggleHidden() {
        this.setState({
            isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
        });
    }

    closeOverlay() {
        this.setState({
            isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
        });
    }

    escFunction(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 27) {
            if (this.state.isHidden === false) {
                this.closeOverlay();
            }

        }
    }

    handleClick(selectedCity) {
        const {cookies} = this.props;
        cookies.set("place", selectedCity);
        this
            .props
            .rerenderfun();

        if (this.state.isLocation) {
            this.setState({
                isHidden: !this.state.isHidden,
                city: cookies.get('place')
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                isLocation: !this.state.isLocation,
                isHidden: !this.state.isHidden,
                city: cookies.get('place')
            })
        }
    }

    render() {

        var overlayClass = 'city-section';
        if (!this.state.isLocation) {
            overlayClass += " city-section visible"
        } else if (this.state.isHidden) {
            overlayClass += " city-section hidden";
        } else {
            overlayClass += " city-section visible"
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" light expand="md">
                    <NavbarBrand href="/">
                        <i className="fa fa-graduation-cap mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Company
                    </NavbarBrand>
                    <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle}/>
                    <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
                        <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/">Favourites</NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink to="/" className="nav-link">Login</NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem>
                                <a className="nav-link" onClick={() => this.toggleHidden()}>
                                    <i className="fa fa-map-marker mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>{this.state.city}</a>
                            </NavItem>
                        </Nav>
                    </Collapse>
                </Navbar>

                <div className={overlayClass} onClick={this.closeOverlay}>
                    <div
                        className="city-content py-5"
                        onClick={(e) => {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    }}>
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row text-center">
                                <div className="col-12">
                                    <h4 className="text-secondary">Select your City</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            {Object
                                .entries(this.props.placelist.result)
                                .map(([k, value]) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div className="row text-center mt-5" key={k}>
                                            <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-5">
                                                <div
                                                    className="card border-0 location-card"
                                                    onClick={() => {
                                                    this.handleClick(value.city)
                                                }}>
                                                    <div className="card-body">
                                                        <img className="location-img" src={cityicon} alt="bangalore"/>
                                                        <p className="font-weight-bold mt-3 mb-0">{value.city}</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })}

                            <div className="row text-center pt-5">
                                <div className="col-12">
                                    <h6 className="text-secondary mt-3 font-italic">Currently we are only in Bangalore</h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withCookies(NavBar);
```

Comment: can you just show your reducer code for loadcity() action ??

Comment: @stack26 I have updated my question with Reducer as well as Action code

Comment: ignore the given answer for now , let me check

Comment: Okay no problem..

Comment: Do you react dev tools .  please use that and check what all is available to your home page component.

Comment: Why you have two function with same name in actions loadInfoData . Please check that. is your eslint not giving you error ??

Comment: @stack26, i checked it, if I am selecting the city from navbar as I mentioned, My props in Homepage is still empty as its not getting re-rendered. but if I refresh the page manually props is being populated.

Comment: @stack26, Sorry about that. Its actually different in my code. I by mistake copied the same function name while creating my question in stack overflow. Sorry. Its actually getInfoData. I have corrected the same.

Comment: Please update question then

Comment: I have updated @stack26.. Sorry again for my mistake. Thank you for pointing that typo

Comment: That I dint notice, I will just correct the code and run my code and let u know in few mins.

Comment: @stack26, Hi, I corrected my mistake and tested it. But still the same issue. Nevertheless one of my error has been corrected. But still child component is not re rendering

Comment: Now try adding debugger in render function and also in cityReducer. and check whther you are hitting those piece of codes. Open your developer console

Comment: @stack26 I tried it. Here I can see that when I click on city selection, Both render function and cityReducer does not run. But if I refresh manually they are running

Comment: Yeah so that's what it mean you are not even calling dispatch function when
you are clicking on city button. Please add a click handler that dispatches the loadInfoData in Navbar component

Comment: I am sorry I am rather new to this, So what should I be doing? My city selection is in NavBar component, so what should I do to make my HomePage call dispatch on click?

Comment: Show me your navbar component and i may assist you

Comment: @stack26, I have updated my question with navBar

Comment: See my answer below. Did it help ??

Comment: @stack26, I just saw the answer, I will try it and let you know in few mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass loadInfoData bind to dispatch to navbar component. You can write mapdispatchtoProps for navbar also .

```
handleClick(selectedCity) {
        const {cookies, loadInfoData} = this.props;
        loadInfoData(selectedCity)
        cookies.set("place", selectedCity);
        this
            .props
            .rerenderfun();

        if (this.state.isLocation) {
            this.setState({
                isHidden: !this.state.isHidden,
                city: cookies.get('place')
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                isLocation: !this.state.isLocation,
                isHidden: !this.state.isHidden,
                city: cookies.get('place')
            })
        }
    }
// add below code for navbar component
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        loadInfoData: (selectedCity) => {
            dispatch(loadInfoData(selectedCity));
        }
    };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(NavBar)
```

Comment: How will I pass the data I receive from loadInfoData to HomePage? I need this data in HomePage component for displaying over there.

Comment: That what , when you are dispatching loadInfodata, api call happens and it updated redux state.  that same redux state is connnected to your home page component. there you will data as a props.

Comment: I did the changes that u showed here.. Now its showing an error saying loadInfoData is not a function. Do I need to add anything else?

Comment: connect your navbar also and pass  loadInfoData in mapdispatchtoprops

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's hard to provide a conclusive answer with just the codes you shared, I mean how you wrote the reducers and all.

Nevertheless, I can suggest some best practices regarding react and redux architecture. Like here in your case does both the parent and child component needs to connect to redux store? as the parent component(Home) is connected and it re-renders so the child component(HomePage) can just receive values with props.

For further studies I suggest going through the following.

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/585

https://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html

personal suggestions or descriptions:

Thing is there are a lot of best practices and standards and none are absolute or one to rule them all type. It solely depends on your needs and application architecture. But what you need is to grasp some concepts like smart and dumb components or container and presentational components, lifting the state up(react docs explains it best). Try to get you head around these concepts. React being a very well engineered library problems like these wont even appear if you architect your application cleverly.

Knowing about the whole application ahead and being able to divide that into many components with as small footprints as possible is the key here I think.

For start you can first design whole state tree of the application (object structure) if not possible then up to some extent and design the component hierarchy by looking at that state tree, you will find that everything is falling into places.

Comment: Add some description here

Comment: So u mean I have to request for redux through for my child component from parent component and pass it as props to child?

Comment: Edited my answer a bit.